# overflow upper incomplete gamma function

Tags: c++, floating-point, special-functions

I want to calculate the following equation:
$$\frac{\theta  \Gamma \left(\kappa+1,\frac{o}{\theta }\right)-o  \Gamma \left(\kappa,\frac{o}{\theta }\right)}{\Gamma (\kappa)}+o+s$$
with $s>0, o>0, \kappa>0, \theta>0$ and in which $\Gamma(\kappa,x)$ represents the upper incomplete gamma function and $\Gamma(\kappa)$ the (true) gamma function.

My current implementation of this equation in c++ using boost [tgamma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/igamma.html)
returns an overflow for large $\kappa$ values.
Is there a way to transform this equation?

Comment: [DLMF 8.8.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.8.E2) might help here, in addition to gammatester's answer: $$\Gamma(k+1,z) = k \,\Gamma(k,z)+z^k e^{-z}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be obvious, but the first thing you should try is to use the
[normalized incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E4) $Q(a,x)=\frac{\Gamma(a,x)}{\Gamma(a)}$
for the two summands in the numerator of your fraction (for the first you have to add one recurrence step for $k+1$). In Boost $Q(a,x)$ is called `gamma_q`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the recurrence step and the normalized incomplete gamma function definition I simplified the formula to:

$$\theta  e^{k \log \left(\frac{o}{\theta }\right)-\frac{o}{\theta }- \ln{\Gamma (\kappa)}} +\theta  \kappa Q \left(\kappa,\frac{o}{\theta }\right)-o Q \left(\kappa,\frac{o}{\theta }\right)+o+s$$

In this equation $Q$ stands for the [normalized upper incomplete gamma function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2#E4) ( [gamma_q](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/igamma.html) in boost):
$$Q_{\kappa,x}=\frac{\Gamma(\kappa,x)}{\Gamma(\kappa)}$$

The $ln(\Gamma(\kappa))$ can be implemented by using [lgamma](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/sf_gamma/lgamma.html) in boost which so far gives me no overflow error for large $\kappa$ values.

Thanks for your support